# Not getting image from Persistant path in Android using unity3d

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I have a script to take screenshot and save that image and to show that image in a plane.

But not getting that texture.

```
private string path;

void Start () {
       path = Application.persistentDataPath;
    }

void captureScreeshot(){ 
    Application.CaptureScreenshot(path + "/Screenshot.png");
    alert.text = "saved";
    StartCoroutine(saveScreenshot()); 
    onetimeBool = false;
}
IEnumerator saveScreenshot(){
    WWW imgfile = new WWW("file://" + path+ "/Screenshot.png");
    yield return imgfile;
    if(imgfile.error==null){
       img = new Texture2D(200, 200, TextureFormat.RGB24, false); 
       imgfile.LoadImageIntoTexture(img);
       alert.text = "got image";
        GameObject.Find("plane").renderer.material.mainTexture = img;

    }else{
       print(imgfile.error);
    }
}
```

Images gets saved.

But I cannot open (load) image in system and android.

Getting error in system :

Couldn't open file /Users/ether/AppData/LocalLow/Company/Project/Screenshot.png

How to get it ???

Comment: FYI, unity3d is the correct tag for this.  The unity tag is for the IoC container from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your path is wrong, you should use: `application.dataPath`, instead of `Application.persistentDataPath`.

Comment: mac os or win?you can find it by **application**