# Why Unity3D Application.CaptureScreenshot for Android doesn't work?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have tried all this links bellow:

[Not getting image from Persistant path in Android using unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809173/not-getting-image-from-persistant-path-in-android-using-unity3d)

https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-3-extension-technical-discussion/capture-screen-problem-androidhelp

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/731509/applicationcapturescreenshot-doesnt-save-anything.html

[I need to set the path for saving the pictures with an application for Android and IOS with UNITY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725548/i-need-to-set-the-path-for-saving-the-pictures-with-an-application-for-android-a)

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/200173/android-how-to-refresh-the-gallery-.html#answer-893069

Every time i build an apk, install it on Android device, nothing happend. 
Log doesn't exists, so i tryed all this links and then go to /DCIM/Camera/ to see if is it saved, no, nothing...

On iOS i did that, and work perfectly.

Here is some code where i stuck... or the things on Android wont work...
I don't know why no error appear or some file strange in folder

```
    void saveImage()
    {
    #if UNITY_ANDROID
    string theFileName = "Screenshot_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy") +"_"+ System.DateTime.Now.ToString("hh_mm_ss")  +".png";

        // Many different test, trying to discovery witch will work...
        Application.CaptureScreenshot( Application.dataPath + "_" + theFileName );
        Application.CaptureScreenshot( "../../../../DCIM/Camera/pathroot_" + theFileName );
        Application.CaptureScreenshot( "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/" + theFileName );
        Application.CaptureScreenshot( "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/" + theFileName );

        StartCoroutine(TakeScreenshot()); // Different test

    #endif
    #if  UNITY_IPHONE
        // This work... so, does not need to be here...
    #endif
    }
```

This is the method that "Coroutine" calls ( copy from one of those links above ):

```
private IEnumerator TakeScreenshot()
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    //INITIAL SETUP
    string myFilename = "Screenshot_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy") +"_"+ System.DateTime.Now.ToString("hh_mm_ss")  +".png";
    string myDefaultLocation = Application.dataPath + "/" + myFilename;

    //EXAMPLE OF DIRECTLY ACCESSING THE Camera FOLDER OF THE GALLERY
    //string myFolderLocation = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/";
    //EXAMPLE OF BACKING INTO THE Camera FOLDER OF THE GALLERY
    //string myFolderLocation = Application.persistentDataPath + "/../../../../DCIM/Camera/";
    //EXAMPLE OF DIRECTLY ACCESSING A CUSTOM FOLDER OF THE GALLERY
    string myFolderLocation = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/";
    string myScreenshotLocation = myFolderLocation + myFilename;

    //ENSURE THAT FOLDER LOCATION EXISTS
    if(!System.IO.Directory.Exists(myFolderLocation)){
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(myFolderLocation);
    }

    //TAKE THE SCREENSHOT AND AUTOMATICALLY SAVE IT TO THE DEFAULT LOCATION.
    Application.CaptureScreenshot(myFilename);

    //MOVE THE SCREENSHOT WHERE WE WANT IT TO BE STORED
    System.IO.File.Move(myDefaultLocation, myScreenshotLocation);

    //REFRESHING THE ANDROID PHONE PHOTO GALLERY IS BEGUN
    AndroidJavaClass classPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject objActivity = classPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");        
    AndroidJavaClass classUri = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");        
    AndroidJavaObject objIntent = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent", new object[2]{"android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED", classUri.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("parse", "file://" + myScreenshotLocation)});        
    objActivity.Call ("sendBroadcast", objIntent);
    //REFRESHING THE ANDROID PHONE PHOTO GALLERY IS COMPLETE

    //AUTO LAUNCH/VIEW THE SCREENSHOT IN THE PHOTO GALLERY
    Application.OpenURL(myScreenshotLocation);

    //AFTERWARDS IF YOU MANUALLY GO TO YOUR PHOTO GALLERY, 
    //YOU WILL SEE THE FOLDER WE CREATED CALLED "myFolder"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This: (Tested & Works):

Application.CaptureScreenshot ("screenshot.png");

store screenshot at:
Application.persistentDataPath, "screenshot.png" i.e data/data/package_name/files

```
void captureScreenshot(string result){
    if (result == "true") {
        StartCoroutine(CaptureScreen());
    } 
}

void OnGUI(){
    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (20, 70, 100, 45), "Click"))
        captureScreenshot ("true");


}
public IEnumerator CaptureScreen()
{
    // Wait for screen rendering to complete
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    Application.CaptureScreenshot ("screenshot.png");

        string Origin_Path = System.IO.Path.Combine (Application.persistentDataPath, "screenshot.png");
        Debug.Log ("Origin_Path save is " + Origin_Path);

        // This is the path of my folder.
        string Path = "/mnt/sdcard/" + "screenshot.png";
        Debug.Log ("Path save is " + Path);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists (Origin_Path)) {
            System.IO.File.Move (Origin_Path, Path);
            Debug.Log ("Path_move save is " + Path);
        }
    jo.Call<bool> ("screenshotHandler", "screenshot.png");
    }
```

If you want to store in gallery without Move again then you can use:

> Application.CaptureScreenshot ("../../../../DCIM/screenshot.png");

If Error: System.IO.File.Exists (Origin_Path)
//returns FALSE even though file exists at Origin_Path.

Please try this:

```
public IEnumerator CaptureScreen()
    {   
        Application.CaptureScreenshot ("../../../../DCIM/"+fileName);
        Debug.Log ("Sanky: Screen Captured");

            while (!File.Exists (filePath)) {
                Debug.Log ("Sanky: File exist at location"+filePath);
                yield return 0; 
            }
/////// do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: Which Unity you are using ?

Comment: 5.3.4f1  : Application.CaptureScreenshot ("screenshot.png"); store screenshot at data/data/packagename/files/xyz.png